# Frequency of words in paragraphs

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

Please help me write a java program that accepts three paragraphs  from the keyboard and finds the frequency of each words from all paragraphs,  using indexof, array and conc methods

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class SearchWord {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
   
        String search = null;
        int c = 0;
        String par = null;
        try {  
            System.out.println("write one paragraph and if you finished press enter ");
            par = in.readLine().toLowerCase();

            System.out.println("Enter the word you want to search");   
            search = in.readLine().toLowerCase();

            int l = search.length();
            for (int b = 0; b < par.length(); b++) {
                int x;
                x = par.indexOf(search, b);
                if (x != -1) {  
                    c++;
                    b = x + l;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

        System.out.println("The occurrence  of word :" + search + " is " + c + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the code that you have written even if it does not work yet.

Comment: It is not related to OOPs. What matters is the logic you have used to solve the problem. You are more likely to get some good help here if you show that you have tried something and/or have read through some articles and seek clarification in your knowledge.

Comment: i just added the code i tried @phoenixsid, this is the best i came up with can you please help out here

Comment: Your code seems to work fine to find a frequency of the given word.  However, there are many points to be clarified: What are `array` and `concat` methods and how they are supposed to be used?  How do you define words and paragraph?  Are you allowed to use methods to split a paragraph into a word?  Are you aware of the approach to use frequency map, are you allowed to use maps?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done so far is read just one line and trying to find the word the user entered. But from your question it seems you want the count of every word.

So why not follow this approach:

1. Remove any punctuation from the string with [String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).
2. Split the line into words (assuming they are separated by spaces) with [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)
3. Create a `Map<String, Long>` that keeps track of each word and its count.
4. Loop through the array of words and for each word you find add it to the map if it is not there yet with a value of 1, or increment the count if it is already there. You can use the [Map.compute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) for this.

When you finish through all the loop your counts will be in the `Map`. This seems to be homework, so I leave it up to you to actually do the code.